# System clock resetting, making conflicts with write stamps

Tags: linux, arch-linux, date-time

My system clock is resetting to a date back in 2016 for some reason and as a work around I reset the date manually every time I boot it. Whenever I boot into Arch with a auto-resetted system date(i.e 2016) it shows me that last write was in the future since I had resetted it to 2018 before getting on with my work so it starts to fix the conflicting write stamps.

I have tried resetting the clock with `date` and `hwclock` but it auto resets everytime.

System Details:

- OS: Arch linux
- Laptop Vendor: HP

Does anyone have a permanent workaround/fix for this?

Comment: Replace the motherboard battery

Comment: I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: You could also run an ntp server, or call ntpclient on startup to sync your clock with the Internet - assuming the system is going to be connected to the Internet alll the time.